# last modified comparison in service method of HttpServlet class

Tags: servlets

I went through HttpServlet class service method and I am confused what this  statement is exactly doing in that method .

```
if (ifModifiedSince < (lastModified / 1000 * 1000)) {
     // If the servlet mod time is later, call doGet()
     // Round down to the nearest second for a proper compare
     // A ifModifiedSince of -1 will always be less
     maybeSetLastModified(resp, lastModified);
     doGet(req, resp);
  } else {
          resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_MODIFIED);
         }
```

How are we calculating lastmodified for comparing it with ifModifiedSince ?